# SQL ASP.NET INSERT troubles (part 2)

Tags: asp.net, sql, oledb

**And i am back again.** 
I have asked a similair question before, but even with the help of the previous anwser and trying it with questionmarks or instead of Add i've tried AddWithValue i didn't have any luck.

I tried to change the txt_Naam to txt_Naam.Text, nothing.

Also putting [] around the columnnames, no luck.
It keeps giving me this "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.".

This time i got nowhere with the code below. 
Probably something small, but i can't figure it out. (Again...)

```
        protected void btn_final_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fact_adres = txt_Naam.Text + "," + txt_Anaam.Text + "," + txt_Adres.Text + "," + txt_Toevoeg.Text + "," + txt_Pcode.Text + "," + txt_Plaats.Text + "," + txt_Email.Text ;
        string fact_adres1 = txt_Naam1.Text + "," + txt_Anaam1.Text + "," + txt_Adres1.Text + "," + txt_Toevoeg1.Text + "," + txt_Pcode1.Text + "," + txt_Plaats1.Text + "," + txt_Email1.Text;

        string a = "1";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "
            + "Data Source=|DataDirectory|webwinkel.accdb";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order (factuur_adres_id, verzend_adres_id, totaalprijs) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@factuur_adres", OleDbType.VarChar, 125).Value = fact_adres;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@verzend_adres", OleDbType.VarChar, 125).Value = fact_adres1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@totaal_prijs", OleDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = a;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Label1.Text = exc.Message;
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            Session["Winkelwagen"] = null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You command text should be

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order (factuur_adres_id, verzend_adres_id, totaalprijs)   VALUES (@factuur_adres,@verzend_adres, @totaal_prijs)";
```

Updated answer:
run your code with setting parameters, directly pass the value and check that it works or not

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order (factuur_adres_id, verzend_adres_id, totaalprijs)   VALUES ('abc','def','adf')";
```

Comment: i tried that, and it still gives me the error. that's why i changed it to questionmarks.

Comment: @Big.S run the above query in your sql server and check that it work there or not ? the syntax is correct.

Comment: i do not use sql server, its is a database on my laptop. I know the syntax is correct, that's why i don't get the error. Maybe it might have to do with the relationships between tables? p.s. the error is still:"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.".

Comment: @Big.S see my updated answer, run your code with out setting parameters.

Comment: thank you for your time, i'll mark your anwser as usefull altough it could not resolve my issue.

Comment: Yes, again the same error: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: @Big.S do one thing, place a break point in your code behind at cmd.CommandText and check that what command text appears also show me.

Comment: forgot about breakpoints.. error is this:"Command text was not set for the command object"

Comment: try cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); also see this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1503573.aspx/1

Comment: you do mean like this right? 'code' conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Order (factuur_adres_id, verzend_adres_id, totaalprijs) VALUES (abc, def, ghi)", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: i tried and it still gives me an error. I personally think there is a problem with the database (which i have not made).
(edit) because when i tried another query in sql it gives me an error on the Order table, why i do not know. But it seems the trouble is with the table and not the code. Atleast that is what i think. thank you for your support these few days tho. If i find my anwser i will post it here as well.

Comment: @Big.S you have a problem in inserting data only or also in viewing data ?

Comment: @Big.S may prob with your access db, create a new simple database and check it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting don't you have to use

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Instead of cmd.ExecuteReader()  ??